# How can I set a report parameter based on the print medium type?

Tags: ssrs-2008, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to toggle some presentation in my SSRS Report based on the print medium the report will be generated on.

I have to do this for a bunch of reports (SalesInvoice, SalesConfirm, SalesQuotation).

The problem is I can't find an access point where I have access to both things:

- In the SalesInvoiceJournalPost class I have access to the printmedium but not the SalesInvoiceContract
- In the SalesInvoiceController class I have access to the SalesInvoiceContract but the printsettings are giving me false values

In `SalesInvoiceJournalPost.init` I try:

```
printSettings = SysOperationHelper::base64Decode(chainFormletterContract.parmPrintersettingsFormletter());
printDestinationSettings = new SRSPrintDestinationSettings(printSettings);

if (printDestinationSettings.printMediumType() == SRSPrintMediumType::Email)
{
    // Can't access Report Parameter from here
}
```

In `SalesInvoiceController.main` I try:

```
printDestination = formLetterController.parmReportContract().parmPrintSettings();
salesInvoiceContract = formLetterController.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract() as SalesInvoiceContract;
salesInvoiceContract.paramMyValue(
    // this is always false because printMedium is always Screen
    printDestination.printMediumType() == SRSPrintMediumType::Email
);
```

Comment: Do you have any sample code you're using. In your `controller` class, have you tried retrieving the print settings with `this.parmReportContract().parmPrintSettings();` or the contract with `this.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract(contract);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can get the SRSPrintDestinationSettings from the controller after all with a few degrees of separation. This is `SalesInvoiceController.outputReport`:

```
PrintMgmtPrintSettingDetail printSettingDetail;
SRSPrintDestinationSettings printDestinationSettings;

printSettingDetail = formLetterReport.getCurrentPrintSetting();
printDestinationSettings = printSettingDetail.parmPrintJobSettings();
salesInvoiceContract.paramMyValue(
    printDestinationSettings.printMediumType() == SRSPrintMediumType::Email
);
```